# how to compile a program using LLVM for different target architecture?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I want to compile the basic program hello.c to native x86 architecture using LLVM / Clang to generate the intermediate and assembly. 
I used the following commands :

```
clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc
llc hello.bc -o hello.s
```

It works perfectly. How do I generate the code for other architecture say SPARC 32 bit? Are there any flags used in clang to specify the architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `llc --version` to get a list of supported targets.  From my machine:

```
$ llc --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.2svn
  Optimized build with assertions.
  Built Aug 30 2012 (23:29:11).
  Default target: mipsel-sde-elf
  Host CPU: corei7-avx

  Registered Targets:
    arm      - ARM
    cellspu  - STI CBEA Cell SPU [experimental]
    cpp      - C++ backend
    hexagon  - Hexagon
    mblaze   - MBlaze
    mips     - Mips
    mips64   - Mips64 [experimental]
    mips64el - Mips64el [experimental]
    mipsel   - Mipsel
    msp430   - MSP430 [experimental]
    nvptx    - NVIDIA PTX 32-bit
    nvptx64  - NVIDIA PTX 64-bit
    ppc32    - PowerPC 32
    ppc64    - PowerPC 64
    sparc    - Sparc
    sparcv9  - Sparc V9
    thumb    - Thumb
    x86      - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64   - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
    xcore    - XCore
```

In your case, you want `llc -march=sparc`, probably.

Answer (score 0):

You can build clang/llvm with certain targets specified. By default without specifying LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD, it will build all targets as shown here https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L269

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it's high in Google search results and could use some information relative to clang 13.x.

The following commands provided helpful information, especially on Windows Releases which don't include the llc program that is commonly mentioned.

> clang -print-effective-triple

> clang -print-targets

> clang -print-multiarch

> clang -print-supported-cpus

> clang -print-target-triple

> clang -print-targets